# Indexing cannot yield multiple results

Tags: matlab

Hi I have this script and it produces this error "Indexing  cannot yield multiple results" whenever I run it.

[mangrove, totalmangrove] = mangrovefringe(map, mangcode, landcode, k);

Comment: Presumably there is a line number that corresponds to this error in your mangrovefringe function.  I would put a breakpoint there, re-run your script and examine the line in detail before executing it: do the variables look correct, do you have any variables identically named to an internal MATLAB function?  For example, I can generate your error by creating and assigning a local variable (**max=0;**) and then trying to use the MATLAB maximum function (**[i,j]=max(1,2);**).

Answer (score 0):

Do you still get this error if you run this command (i.e., with only one output argument)?  Looks like perhaps you need to restructure your output.  Perhaps by assigning different indices to each output variable?

```
oneOutput = mangrovefringe(map, mangcode, landcode, k);
```